# How to fix windows 7 after installing windows 8

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, windows-8-preview

I followed this guide from howtogeek:
http://www.howtogeek.com/75286/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-8-without-re-partitioning-using-vhd/

I was successfully able to boot to windows 8, but now I can't boot to windows 7. I always get redirected to the screen that you see when you choose to repair Windows 7 from an install CD. The one with the choice like startup repair, command prompt, and system restore.

How do I revert back to the state where I can use Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation method uses an old ps-script for Windows 7 and it is not clear if it works 100% for Windows 8 Dev.Prev. as well.

What you can do is delete the existing entry for Windows 7 in the BCD and create a new one. 
This can be done easy with [Visual BCD Editor](http://boyans.my3gb.com).
Download and install. Run it (eventually wait for .NET version to be downlaoded and installed on first run)

Select the entry for Windows 7 in tree view right-click and select "delete".
After entry for Win7 has been deleted right-click again in tree view and select "Create missing Windows loaders". This will create a new Windows 7 loader (and loaders for other installed Windows versions - XP, Vista if present). Change wording of entry using F2.

Reboot - select the new menu entry which should boot Windows 7.

If there are still problems your Windows 7 is messed up and should be repaired using recovery.
It is possible that automatic recovery does not fix all problems on first run - reboot and run it for not more than three times. 
If still errors - reinstallation of Windows 7 can be considered.