# Restoring the Windows 7 boot loader (after uninstalling Windows 8)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, bootloader

A while back I installed Windows 8 Consumer Preview on my PC.

As expected, I quickly grew bored of it, and uninstalled it. I removed the whole partition on which I had installed the OS, and everything seemed okay, until I rebooted.

Whenever I reboot, I'm displayed with the Windows 8 boot loader (even though I deleted the **whole** partition it was on?), and I can't choose any operating system to boot into. It just says that there was an error.

I did some research, and found out that I should use EasyBCD, but I'm not sure if I can burn it on to a CD and then boot from it? (I have only 700 MB CDs available)
Or if there's another tool that I could burn on to a CD that would let me remove the Windows 8 boot loader, and just let me boot to Windows 7.

Comment: I do believe this is not a duplicate, especially because my problem is mainly with Windows 8, not Ubuntu.

Comment: Exact duplicate of [How to fix windows 7 after installing windows 8](http://superuser.com/questions/341211/how-to-fix-windows-7-after-installing-windows-8), other duplicates can be found under `Linked` in the side bar. Please check them out as they all contain solutions to your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can restore the Windows 7 bootloader from a Windows 7 DVD.

The easy way is to boot from the DVD and use Startup Repair.

The slightly harder way is to go into the command prompt after booting from the DVD, and use these commands:

```
bootrec /fixmbr

bootrec /fixboot

bootsect /nt60 all
```

Of course you have to be careful when trying to replace the bootloader, as it can result in a failure to boot. But in your case, it doesn't work anyway, so you can try these commands.

More information, and more things you can try can be found here: [How to manually repair Windows 7 boot problems](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/).

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows 7 Setup DVD and boot into instalation. After this select Repair your computer -> Command prompt. In the command prompt window, enter the following to repair your boot loader:

bootrec /rebuildbcd

After a few moments, it should detect your Windows installation and ask if you want to add it to the boot loader.  Enter Y to add it, then exit the command prompt and reboot your computer when you’re finished.

Answer (score 0):

before removing win 8 you should have revert the bootloader to win 7. Win 8 bootloader is fancy but it takes more time so I use win 7 bootloader instead to avoid restart when choosing another OS. Just login to Win 7 and rebuild the MBR using easyBCD just add anything and delete it then save. also if you want to go back to win 8 boatloader just login to win 8 then use easybcd add an entry then delete it and save.

Comment: Could you explain how the OP is to "login to Win 7", given that he says he cannot boot into any OS from the Windows 8 bootloader?