# Restore Windows bootloader on Virtual Machine

Tags: windows-7, boot, virtual-machine, grub, bootloader

I recently p2v'ed my old Computer into a virtual machine. Since it had a dual-boot and I only copied the Windows partition this broke GRUB. I can still boot Windows with Rescatux though. So my question is if I can restore the original Windows Bootloader so I don't have to select "find any operating system" in Rescatux when i boot the VM.

Comment: Also see [Restoring the Windows 7 boot loader (after uninstalling Windows 8)?](http://superuser.com/questions/412777/restoring-the-windows-7-boot-loader-after-uninstalling-windows-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load a Windows installation disc from ISO on your VM, choose **Repair** when prompted with the **Install Now** screen and opt to open a Command Prompt. There you should type:

```
bootrec /fixboot
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method completely rebuilds everything, you can use it from your favorite Windows Setup. Just use Shift-F10 to fire up a command prompt without going through unnecessary steps.

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

This installs a completely pristine Windows Boot Manager to c: and adds Windows to it. You may need to find the right drive letter first, though.

`bcdboot` may not be in `%PATH%`. You can find it on your Windows partition, like this:

```
c:\windows\system32\bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

Comment: `bdcboot C:\windows /s C:` give me `Failure when attempting to copy boot files`

Comment: You did make sure C: is the right partition? Did you attempt to run this command after booting from Windows Setup, as described?

Comment: I missed the part about Windows setup. When do I have to press Shift+F10?

Comment: It’s always available as soon as the GUI has finished starting. `bcdboot` can also be run from within Windows, but needs to run with admin rights. Unless you explicitly started `cmd` as admin, it runs with restricted rights.